# High speed display from Andor in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, cython, camera-calibration, pyqtgraph

I am currently working with Andor Neo CCD for high-speed image acquisition. By programming in Cython/Python, I am successfully able to control the functionalities of the CCD. For Live Image acquisitions, I'm able to acquire each frame within the desired time frame. Though I'm unable to display all of these acquired images within the same time frame. Any suggestions for high-speed image display?

PS- To get an idea of the time frame.
To only acquire `300` images of size `1392 x 1040` it takes `8.33seconds`, while to display each of them after acquiring takes `13.45 seconds`

Comment: Hey, I remember your last question. Did you try with pyqtgraph?

Comment: I am working on PyQt GUI platform along with pyqtgraph.1. I want to display a sequence of images on the QGraphics View at high speed, but following `ImageItem-video` example of pyqtgraph made it look like animation which is not I require.2. I wanted to know the options to do so. Hence the post.